# Accessing Private Property value in C# 6.0 without creating it

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I understand that reading from the [WebConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) is slow, so I want to minimize my use of it.

Say I have the following readonly property in my code:

```
public string SiteLogo {
    get {
        return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SITE_LOGO"];
    }
}
```

In C# 6.0, I can shorten this so that the "getter" has the default value:

```
public string SiteLogo { get; } =  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SITE_LOGO"];
```

This, it looks like, would be called every time the class is instantiated, whether that Property is ever used or not.

It looks like the most efficient call is still to declare a Private variable to use in the Property:

```
public string SiteLogo
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_siteLogo))
        {
            _siteLogo = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SITE_LOGO"];
        }
        return _siteLogo;
    }
}
private string _siteLogo;
```

This still requires me to create Private variables for all of my getters, which seems overly tedious.

I have discarded the idea of using a Session variable, because reading that and casting it to a String seems like it would still incur more overhead.

I would like to see is a way to Auto Assign the Private Property if it is needed.

If the compiler called each Property's Private field `#this`, I could use something along these lines:

```
public string SiteLgo
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(#this))
        {
            #this = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SITE_LOGO"];
        }
        return #this;
    }
}
```

Even better, I should not ever need to explicitly tell the code block to return the Private Property, since that is the getter's job:

```
public string SiteLogo
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(#this))
        {
            #this = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SITE_LOGO"];
        }
    }
}
```

If a technique to do that currently exists, I don't know the name of what to call it to look it up.

Have I missed the better way to do what I am after (accessing the Private value without having to create it)?

Comment: Hard to come up with a reason to not make it *static* so it is only ever done once.  You did not mention any reason to make it an instance property so that's probably what you want to do.

Comment: @HansPassant - I ....don't know. I think I'll go ahead and do that. I'd still like to know the best way to access these Private Auto Properties. I see the `Lazy<T>` answer, and that could be what I was searching for. The static variables would still be better in this particular case, though.

Comment: You keep saying things like "I understand it to be slow" and "seems like it would still incur more overhead". Have you actually measured the performance?

Comment: @svick - no, I have not. This knowledge only comes from reading best practices I come across online. If a company were to pay me while I sat there and wrote out test cases, I would be happy to measure and report back on performance.

Comment: @jp2code If you care about performance, then you really should measure it, instead of believing what you remember someone on the internet said. If you don't care about performance, then this question is pointless, just use what's most readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed some class that was introduced in .NET 4.0: `Lazy<T>`:

```
private readonly string _siteLogo = new Lazy<string>(() => WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SITE_LOGO"]);

// Lazy<T>.Value will call the factory delegate you gave
// as Lazy<T> constructor argument
public string SiteLogo => _siteLogo.Value;
```

BTW, I wouldn't use lazy-loading for this case... at the end of the day, application settings are already loaded into memory and you aren't accessing from the file.

In fact, `AppSettings` is a `NameValueCollection` and it uses hash codes to store keys ([taken from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> The hash code provider dispenses hash codes for keys in the
>   NameValueCollection. The default hash code provider is the
>   CaseInsensitiveHashCodeProvider.

In other words, accessing `AppSettings` has a time complexity `O(1)` (constant).

I would use lazy-loading if you would need to parse settings some way to avoid re-parsing them everytime.